# Pandas group by function to do different methods if index in list

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, pandas-groupby

I'm wondering if its possible to create your own groupby function that runs a different method for the output in a single column depending on if the index is in some list or not. For example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID' : [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3],
                   'Data' : [5, 7, 6, 13, 14, 11, 10, 2, 4, 3]})

some_list = [2, 3]
```

I want to group by ID column, and return an average of the Data column (`df.groupby('ID').mean()` for most values) However, if ID is in `some_list` then I would like the average to be calculated as the sum of Data divided by 4 (`df.groupby('ID').sum()/4`). The output for the above would look as below:

```
   ID   Data
0   1   6.00
1   2  12.00
2   3   2.25
```

I know I could do both methods separately and join into one column after doing the groupby, but I was wondering if its possible to do this in one step? Maybe with `df.groupby('ID').apply(function)`?

I've looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31732647/if-statement-in-grouped-pandas-dataframe), but it didn't help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `groupby` with `apply` and a condition:

```
df.groupby('ID', as_index=False)['Data'].apply(lambda x: x.sum() / 4 if x.name in some_list else x.mean())
```

Output:

```
   ID   Data
0   1   6.00
1   2  12.00
2   3   2.25
```

Comment: This method did exactly what I need it, but I've just used pylint to analyse my code, and it gives a warning:  `W0640 (cell-var-from-loop): Cell variable defined in loop`. I don't know if this is just because of where it sits in my code (I use it in a for loop) or not.

Comment: @EmiOB That is surely not from my code, it must be from your other code, pandas has different warnings.

Comment: just tested and its not from your code, I've obviously messed something up

Comment: @EmiOB Cool! Hope you can fix it

Comment: It works how I want it do, so it's just a warning so maybe I can ignore it :p

Comment: @EmiOB You can search on Google how to disable warnings :)

Comment: I guess its something to do with the fact that I'm using this bit of code in a for loop, so it defines lambda multiple times. Maybe its better to define it as a function first and call that each time

Answer (score 1):

If performance is important dont use `groupby.apply`, you can filter rows for aggregate `sum` with division and for aggregate `mean`:

```
s = df[df['ID'].isin(some_list)].groupby('ID')['Data'].sum().div(4)
df = s.combine_first(df.groupby('ID')['Data'].mean()).reset_index()

print (df)
   ID   Data
0   1   6.00
1   2  12.00
2   3   2.25
```

Here is alternative solution:

```
df = df.groupby('ID')['Data'].agg(['sum','mean']).reset_index()
df['Value'] = np.where(df['ID'].isin(some_list), df.pop('sum').div(4), df.pop('mean'))
print (df)
   ID  Value
0   1   6.00
1   2  12.00
2   3   2.25
```